# Can't get WHERE NOT EXISTS to work

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables number & allocation.  allocation has the number primary column as a foreign key.  I have a view that gives me all the numbers that exist in the allocation table.  I am however looking to do the reverse, looking for numbers that are UN-assigned / not inside the allocation table.  I created a NOT EXISTS however, the results come out blank.  The structure and view is as follows;

```
number (table)
  NID  primary
  number

allocation (table)
  AID primary
  NID Foreign Key to number table
```

My view structure:

```
CREATE VIEW vNoAllocationNumber AS
    SELECT NID 
    FROM number
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NID
                      FROM number, allocation
                      WHERE allocation.NID = number.NID)
```

Comment: To loose your hair is to let it roam free. I think you mean "lose".

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
CREATE VIEW vNoAllocationNumber AS
    SELECT NID 
      FROM number n
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT 1
                     FROM allocation a
                    WHERE a.NID = n.NID
           )
         ;
```

you can also exploit left-joining (unless allocation.NID constitutes an AK,
 this technique will only work for UN-assigned NIDs):

```
CREATE VIEW vNoAllocationNumber AS
    SELECT NID 
      FROM number n
 LEFT JOIN allocation a ON ( a.NID = n.NID )
     WHERE a.NID IS NULL
         ;
```